# SSL Error ("certificate verify failed') While Accessing Bitbucket Through Atlassian Python API

Tags: python, api, ssl, bitbucket

I am trying to connect to Bitbucket programmatically using the Atlassian Python API

```
from atlassian import Bitbucket

bitbucket = Bitbucket(my_url, my_user, my_pwd)

data = bitbucket.project_list()

print(next(data))
```

While running the ebove code, i get the following SSL error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

How do I resolve this error WITHOUT USING sslverify=false?

Should I download a certificate from bitbucket and provide it in our code? If yes how do we do that?

Comment: "Should I download a certificate from bitbucket and provide it in our code?" No, you should figure out which certificate authority is used to sign the bitbucket certificate and then configure the corresponding CA certificate as a trusted certificate authority. [This article](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/how-to-determine-certificate-authority/) has some suggestions for figuring out the signing authority for the server.

Comment: Should I create a certificate first and use it? I am new to automating this certificate creation and certificate authority